# ruby on rails 5 lambda syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a migration file `create_subject` (code of which is below), a `Subject` class contains scopes using lambda syntax. When I call `Subject.visible`, I get syntax errors.

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string "name"
      t.integer "position"
      t.boolean "visible", :default=>false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :subjects
  end
end
```

[This is my Subject class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxDJO.png)

Console error log

```
irb(main):003:0> Subject.visible
SyntaxError: C:/Users/SS/Sites/simple_cms/app/models/subject.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
scope :visible, -> { where (:visible => true) }
                                   ^
C:/Users/SS/Sites/simple_cms/app/models/subject.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting ')'
scope :invisible, -> { where (:visible => false) }
                                     ^
C:/Users/SS/Sites/simple_cms/app/models/subject.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '|'
scope :search, -> {|query| where (["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }
                ^
C:/Users/SS/Sites/simple_cms/app/models/subject.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
scope :search, -> {|query| where (["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not put space before opening parenthesis when calling methods. It should be like this

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  scope :visible, -> { where(:visible => true) }
  scope :invisible, -> { where(:visible => false) }
  scope :sorted, -> { order("position ASC") }
  scope :search, ->(query) { where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }
  # and so on ...
end
```

Comment: (THANK YOU, for replying. Looks like most of the errors are fixed. BUT):

irb(main):001:0> Subject.visible
SyntaxError: C:/Users/SS/Sites/simple_cms/app/models/subject.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected '|'
scope :search, -> {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }

Comment: I literally cant be more thankful to you sir @Michal. I felt like i've lost learning this language.
Thank you so so very much...

Comment: @SafiUllah You can accept the answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to put query in pipes `|query|` then use:

```
scope :search,lambda{|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }
```

instead of

```
scope :search, ->(query) { where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"]) }
```